# Angular Universal + Nunjucks results in node-gyp error

Tags: angular, webpack, nunjucks

On OS X 10.14.1, when using Nunjucks as a templating engine for Angular Universal, I receive:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package' in '/Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/lvs-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 67:16-37
 @ ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js
 @ ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
 @ ./node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.js
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/nunjucks/src/node-loaders.js
 @ ./node_modules/nunjucks/src/loaders.js
 @ ./node_modules/nunjucks/index.js
 @ ./server.ts
```

When building my server.ts. Here's my webpack.server.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/node_modules/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

This build process works perfectly fine on Windows 10. I have tried:

Completely re-installing Node 10, 9 and 8 via nvm.
Following suggestions at https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/issues/229 and countless other articles.

It seems node-gyp can't export the package.json from this line in node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 67:

```
/**
 * Export the contents of the package.json.
 */

proto.package = require('../package')
```

Commenting out the above line does not seem to actually affect the build, but does throw several other warnings.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've seen your approach of using nunjucks with Angular Universal and it looks really interesting, I'm having performance issues with universal. Do you have any insights / post where I can read more about it? Thanks!

Comment: Not on OS X unfortunately. I switched to my Windows 10 machine and it works just fine. What kind of performance issues are you seeing?

Comment: I'd need OSX and Ubuntu :(. Rendering is too slow using Angular Universal compared to Nunjucks, it takes around 200 ms for a 70 items page, whereas pure Nunjucks renders it in around 40 ms... with the same API call.

Comment: Interesting. I've seen the opposite when using Universal, at least with applications hosted on Heroku.